# How to get the size of an InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, content-length

I'm having an `InputStream` from a `ProcessBuilder` that acutally reads the `stdout` stream.

Question: how can I know the size of that inmemory `InputStream`, so I can write it to a `HttpResponse` http header?

```
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
int bytes;
while ((bytes = br.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes);
}

//how can I know the size of the inmemory stream/file written?
//response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());
```

Comment: You won't know until you have read it all.  The output could be endless.

Comment: You are better off returning this as a stream to the browser.

Comment: Refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746978/java-inputstream-size

Comment: Wait; what tells you that the content is text at all? Also, you don't even specify the encoding on your reader (edit: from the comments it seems that this is not text)

Comment: Just read and write in a loop using a fixed size buffer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey could you give an example on how to return this as a stream?

Comment: @membersound how you do it depends on your library e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response Do you know you need to set a length?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as the size of an input stream. Consider a program which never exits, or a socket peer which never stops sending. And you don't need to know to write it to an `HttpResponse` header. The `Content-length` is managed automatically for you.

Comment: @BalusC Better use a temp file why?

Comment: @BalusC 'Memory friendly' how? According to your comment, the memory usage doesn't exceed 'the buffer'. Using a temp file only adds latency: it doesn't really save memory.

Comment: @BalusC You haven't answered my question.

Comment: @BalusC But he doesn't need to set the content-length. `HttpResponse` will do that for him, and chunk it too if necessary.

Comment: @BalusC Adding latency just so that progress can be reported isn't  much of an idea. The real progress is the progress of the `Process` being executed, and that remains hidden from the client.

Comment: @membersound EJP is right, providing a stream to the response without explicit content length makes the HTTP response *chunked* effectively streaming data back to the client without limitations. With streams you should not assume you know the stream size upfront

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to set the content length header, you'll need to read the entire stream before writing to the response OutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
}
response.setContentLength(out.size();
out.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
```

Note: With this approach you've now read the entire stream into memory, this will have an impact on available memory and likely won't scale well.

Comment: It is all pointless, as Java already manages the Content-length for you.

Comment: huh? no it doesn't? Headers (including content-length) are sent before writing to the outputstream. If you write a single byte to the outputstream, you can't set a header at that point. So, the stream will be sent without a content-length header, meaning the client can NOT display a percentage complete whilst the stream is being received

Comment: Huh, yes it does. Try it some time, like I did 20 years ago, and again last month.

Comment: Absolute nonsense. Http protocol is headers first, then response body. Sure you can write to the response OutputStream without setting content length header. But if you set it you set it there's benefits. Or maybe you've got a filter in the chain doing it for you? Eg gzip filter

Comment: So in other words you still haven't tried it. Don't waste any more of my time until you have. You will get a surprise.

Comment: huh? of course I've tried it. If you don't set the content-length header on the response, the content-length header will not be set. If in your application you are not setting the content-length header and you can see a content-length header on the response in the client then something is doing it for you. This is NOT default behaviour and you likely have a filter configured which is doing it for you. You say java manages the content-length header.. which framework? There's 100s of web frameworks to choose from in java. Saying java does this for you is nonsense

Comment: The only two frameworks under discussion here are (1) `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, which behaves as I described, and which is in the JRE, and (2) `HttpServletResponse`, ditto, which is in the Servlet API. The former outputs a Content-length header automatically, unless you're using chunked transfer mode, and the latter *uses* chunked transfer mode by default. In neither case do they need any assistance from the application programmer. I have twenty years' worth of working code that demonstrates it.

Comment: Most JavaWebServers buffer ServletOutputStreams up to a certain length. If you close the stream before the bufferlength is reached it will write a content length header and the buffered bytes. If you write more bytes it might use a chunked encoding or more likely an indefinite body which requires the connection to be closed after serving it. This should be avoided.

Comment: For tomcat it is for example documented here in doGet() https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

Comment: "The content length is automatically set if the entire response fits inside the response buffer." I stand corrected

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int b;
    while ((b = is.read()) != -1)
        os.write(b);
    response.setContentLength(os.size());
    response.getOutputStream().write(os.toByteArray());
```

Comment: It is never necesary to set the content-length in the Java JDK, and using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` here is just a waste of time and space. And doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user207421 That's just not true. 
I need to handle content-length myself and this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Lerk You think you need that why?

Comment: @user207421 I had some library that required this. 
But I don't remember which one after two years, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

   byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
   log.message("bytes .lenght "+bytes.length);

            if (bytes.length > 400000)
//some byte range limit`enter code  can add any byte range
              {
                throw new Exception("File Size is larger than 40 MB ..");
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

An `InputStream` inherently doesn't have a size. It could conceivably keep delivering bytes forever. Or the producing end could end the stream without warning.

If you must find out the length, then you have to read to the end, counting the bytes, and report the length when you finish.

You're worrying about HTTP's `Content-length` header, and you've got a point. The fact is that the original version of HTTP was not designed for large, dynamically generated content. The protocol inherently expects you to know the size of the content before you start writing it - yet how is that possible if it's (for example) an ongoing chat, or the output of a video camera?

The solution is HTTP's `chunked transfer encoding`. Here you don't set a `Content-Length` header. You set `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, then write the content as chunks, each of which has a size header.

The HTTP RFC has details one this, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding is slightly more friendly.

However most HTTP APIs hide this detail from you. Unless you are developing a web library from scratch (perhaps for academic reasons), you shouldn't have to think about `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding`.