# How to convert processing of batch file into percentage

Tags: java, batch-file, io

I have following piece of code :

```
    File file = new File("//path/to/BatchFile");
    long fileLength = 0 ;
    if(file.exists()){
      fileLength = file.length();
    }

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + "//path/to/batchfile");
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String s;
    long bytesRead=0;

    while (( s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bytesRead = bytesRead + s.getBytes().length + 2; // forget about +2
            int progress = (int) (( bytesRead/  fileLenth)*100 );
            System.out.println("Progress : "+ progress);

    }
```

What I am trying to do is running a batch file and converting it to BufferedReader to calculate the percentage for progress bar. But my percentage goes beyond 100.

Help me correcting what i am doing wrong or let me know how to convert the 'process' part into percentage.

Comment: What does the `+ 2` part mean ?

Comment: I think he means carriage return

Comment: Why is bytesRead a double? Shouldn't it be an integer value (int or perhaps long)

Comment: This does not make sense to me. What has the output from the batchfile to do with its file length? Does it print itself? Btw: You should skip the rest if the file does not exist. Otherwise you'll run into exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to get the size of an InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501489/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-inputstream)

> An InputStream inherently doesn't have a size. It could conceivably
>   keep delivering bytes forever. Or the producing end could end the
>   stream without warning.
>
> If you must find out the length, then you have to read to the end,
>   counting the bytes, and report the length when you finish.

I assume that the batch file returns a result and you do not want to have the size of the batch file.

Because the batch returns a result as stream you do not know the stream size.
If the batch writes the result into another file, you can start reading the result-file by using the file length.

**UPDATE**

You pointed the the batch logic.
The Batch checks out SVN projects and you want to have the number of checked out elements. This is a different request!

Its more like another SVN request you have to use. You can first ask for the SVN children of a specific folder. Afterwards you have to read the checkout-stream result and analyze the content.

You have to search for key-words defining, that a checkout command finsihed(successful and not successful). This will increase the progress counter and not the stream bytes.

Comment: The batch file contains svn commands to checkout projects. how can I get total checkout projects?? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Markus Exactly this is what I wanted. Can I use SVNKit api to achieve this??

Comment: @Fildor Thanks much, I think you have provided me the direction what Markus has pointed out.