# File not uploaded to s3 bucket

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file to aws-s3 bucket using spring mvc rest api. Here is my credentials format  to access s3 bucket

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = Access key id
aws_secret_access_key = secret access key
```

Here is my Java code:

```
@RestController
public class UploadController {

private static String bucketName= "mp4-upload-1";
private static String keyName= "secret access key";
public static final Logger logger=LogManager.getLogger(UploadController.class);

@RequestMapping(value="/uploadVideo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadVideo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {


    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    try {
        System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");

        InputStream is=file.getInputStream();

        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName,is,new ObjectMetadata()).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));


    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                "means your request made it " +
                "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                " for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                "means the client encountered " +
                "an internal error while trying to " +
                "communicate with S3, " +
                "such as not being able to access the network.");
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

}

The problem is I am not getting any error but file is not uploading to s3-bucket. am I missing anything here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are they your real credentials? I suggest you remove them immediately.

Comment: do not just remove it, disable that key. As usually people have some custom scripts that looks for AWS Credentials, and will spin up lots of EC2 instances.

Comment: Remove the credentials from here and generate a new key (don't share that elsewhere). SO can still look into the issue without requiring the credentials

Comment: This is not real credentials however edited..thanks for informing me...

Comment: use multipart upload method http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Comment: @ AntiCode the problem is how can I get filepath..since I am using postman to send form data..so how can i get file path location from postman request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content length should be specified on the request when the stream is uploaded directly to S3.

```
ObjectMetadata objMetadata = new ObjectMetadata()
objMetadata.setContentLength(20L);
```

> When uploading directly from an input stream, content length must be
>   specified before data can be uploaded to Amazon S3. If not provided,
>   the library will have to buffer the contents of the input stream in
>   order to calculate it. Amazon S3 explicitly requires that the content
>   length be sent in the request headers before any of the data is sent.

[Refer this for content length calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501489/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-inputstream)

**Alternate Approach:-**

Use `org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray()` to convert the stream to `byte[]` and upload the byte array to S3.

Comment: Hi My code is working now. The problem was I placed the credentials in wrong placed. However, This time I have created IAM user and get access_key_id and secret_access_key and then managed this credentials inside code rather than put in the home directory. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have gone different approach, but your suggestion is working too.